# Polya theorem unequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a little hint. I have a complex function $f(z) = z^2 - 2 $. I have to show that $(x^2+y^2)^2 \leq 4(x^2 - y^2)$ for all $z$ with $|f(z)| \leq 2$.

I would start like this:

$|f(z)| \leq 2$

$|z^2 -2| \leq 2$

$|(x + iy)^2 -2| \leq 2$

$|x^2 + 2ixy - y^2 -2| \leq 2$

But I don´t know further steps. Maybe someone has an hint for me?

Comment: Perhaps: $(x^2-y^2-2)^2 + (2xy)^2 \le 4$?

Answer (score 1):

Square the whole thing:

$$|x^2 + 2ixy - y^2 -2| \leq 2\implies (x^2-y^2-2)^2+4x^2y^2<4\implies$$

$$(x^2-y^2)^2-4(x^2-y^2)+4x^2y^2<0\implies (x^2+y^2)^2<4(x^2-y^2)$$

Comment: Thanks alot! Helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

*A variant*:
\begin{align}
|f(z)|^2=(z^2-2)(\bar z^2-2)\le 4&\iff (z\bar z)^2-2(z^2+\bar z^2)+4\le 4 \\
& \iff  (z\bar z)^2\le 2(z^2+\bar z^2),
\end{align}
which yields explicitly
$$x^2+y^2\le 2\bigl((x^2+2ixy-y^2)+(x^2-2ixy-y^2)\bigr)=4(x^2-y^2)$$